Instance has unexpected rotation after Realize Instances
I place an instance (Lv1) on branch level 0. Lv1 takes branch Lv2 as instance. Lv2 takes Lv3 (cube) as instance.
I use Align Euler to Vector node, Roate Rotation node and Curve Tangent node to rotate Lv1 around Lv0's tangent direction. Lv2 has the same nodes waiting for rotating later. At the beginning, when Lv1 rotates, Lv2 follows and keep the orientation relative to Lv1. So far so good.
However, when I put the Realize Instances node to Lv2, things go wrong. If I rotate the Lv1, Lv2 rotates as well, with an unexpected rotation behavior.
I need Realize Instances node to decrease instance amount and maintain Lv3 size. In this case，how can I remove the unexpected rotation ?
Any help will be appreciated.








Replace the Resample Curve node with the Curve to Points node and connect its data to the Instance on Points node. Then use the Rotate Instances node for rotation.
There will be no more additional rotation comparing with Align Euler to Vector of curve tangent. It may not be the only answer, but it should be a better way in this case.

